# How to select an element having a backslash in its id attribute

Tags: javascript

While going through official doc ,I am unable to understand that for matching the first div ,how they have written four backslash(\) ,In my opinion there should be two backslash.I am unable to find the valid logic for this reason

```
 <div id="foo\bar"></div>
 <div id="foo:bar"></div>
 document.querySelector('#foo\\\\bar');  // It matches the first div
```

Comment: Have you tested the code with 1, 2, 3, and 4 back-slashes? I think you'll find out why eventually. Also, that's a horrible way of identifying elements.

Comment: One each to escape slash `\` and escaper slash `\`

Answer (score 6):

This is due to the browser escapes the backslash in the id attribute.
So it will become

```
<div id="foo\\bar"></div>
```

So inorder to select the element we need to provide `\\\\` to select the element.

```js
var elements = document.querySelector('#foo\\\\bar');
console.log(elements);
var elements = document.querySelector('#foo\\bar');
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<div id="foo\bar"></div>
<div id="foo:bar"></div>
```

Update based on comment
You can read more information regarding this in following links:-

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters

Comment: Thanks ,Can u suggest me some reference from where I can learn these things .I will Be highly thankful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You have two double backslashes. As you know, the backslashe is a "escape" character.

So your selector string become:

```
#foo\\bar <--- to have this string in a variable, you need to use '#foo\\\\bar'
```

Now, the double backslash that left (in the string) will be used (again as a escape character) by the querySelector.

You can checkout more details about how selectors can be written [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/#lex).

Answer (score 0):

It's encoding rules to put diffrence with some special characters. The `'\b'` is a combination of charactere that mean backspace so if you don't want to mean it you have to write `'\\b'`, the second step that you have to encode `'\'` on your string so to cover this case you have to write `'\\'`. So for that your output must be `"foo\\\\bar"`